# What could cause a 302 redirect?

Tags: facebook, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-302

I have a wordpress site and I have a blog. When I try to share my blog post on FB http://videoefekt.cz/?p=472 , it shows the thumb of my homepage. I tried to change permalinks to clear, deactivate plugins and chceck .htaccess file, everything looks fine, but the FB sharing debugger shows I have 302 HTTP Redirect to my homepage, can anyone tell me what could cause this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simulate the facebook crawler access to your site and it made redirect to home page when using ipv6 address. Possibly you have misconfig when the request is from ipv6 address.

```
curl -H "User-Agent: facebookexternalhit/1.1" "http://videoefekt.cz/?p=472" -vvvv -6
* About to connect() to videoefekt.cz port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 2a02:2b88:1:4::a6...
* Connected to videoefekt.cz (2a02:2b88:1:4::a6) port 80 (#0)
> GET /?p=472 HTTP/1.1
> Host: videoefekt.cz
> Accept: */*
> User-Agent: facebookexternalhit/1.1
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Thu, 04 Jan 2018 04:16:32 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
< Link: <http://videoefekt.cz/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
< Set-Cookie: _icl_current_language=cs; expires=Fri, 05-Jan-2018 04:16:33 GMT; Max-Age=86400; path=/
< Set-Cookie: wfvt_3708104896=5a4daaa1e2090; expires=Thu, 04-Jan-2018 04:46:33 GMT; Max-Age=1800; path=/; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=8a1a1d9247ac9d9707b616c6c0ad2ccc; path=/
< Upgrade: h2,h2c
< Connection: Upgrade
< Location: http://videoefekt.cz/
< Vary: User-Agent
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< 
* Connection #0 to host videoefekt.cz left intact
```

Comment: You are right, in DNS records the IPV6 is showing address of my old webhosting, thanks a lot !